# Как распознавать клонированных объектов?

Tags: unity3d

Для игры создал клоны фишек. Фишки из начальных координат должны переместиться в конечные, которые для каждой фишки разные. Как распознать клоны, что бы если клон придет в свою координату можно было это как-то зафиксировать? думал через тэги, теги надо делать в ручную, а количество фишек задается из текстового файла.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1):

Можете в классе фишек добавить поле id, для каждого клона оно должно быть уникальным, для этого храните глобальную переменную, в которой хранится максимальное уже использованное значение id, и прибавляйте 1 к нему для нового id. А по id можно уже и фишки опознать)))

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: А как правильно при создании обратиться к классу фишек?

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Если у вас собственный класс фишек, то просто добавляете в конструктор фишки аргумент id.

Comment: У всех получается ID последней фишки(

Comment: Смотрите, пусть у вас есть переменная max_id, которая хранит максимальный использованный индекс. Тогда при создании новой фишки указывайте max_id + 1, а после создания делайте max_id += 1. Тогда будут разные id. А изначально max_id сделайте равным например -1